# Mockito: Having trouble executing method in class annotated with @MockBean

Tags: spring, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I'm new to Mockito, so I apologize if there is a simple solution.

I have a test class set up:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
public class dummyServiceTest{
  @InjectMocks ServiceA serviceA;

  @MockBean ServiceB serviceB;

  @BeforeEach
  void before() throws Exception {
    openMocks(this);
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(serviceA, "maxRetries", 3);
  }

  @Test
  public void serviceATest() {
    ...
    serviceA.someMethod1();
    ...
  }

  ...
}
```

ServiceA class:

```
@Component
public class ServiceA {
  @Autowired ServiceB serviceB;

  ...

  public void someMethod1() {
    ...
    serviceB.someMethod2();
    ...
  }
}
```

ServiceB class:

```
public class ServiceB {
  ...

  public void someMethod2() {
    ...
  }
}
```

TLDR: a method in the ServiceA class is called in the test class. That method calls a method in ServiceB

When running my tests, I noticed that none of the logs in someMethod2 were displayed. I tried running in debugging mode and noticed that when I add a breakpoint in that method, it is never hit. Only when I add a breakpoint to the very first line of the method does it reach that endpoint, but doesn't proceed to the next line in that method. Also, when it reaches the first line of the method, it does not have access to any global variables or even the arguments (note: I didn't show any arguments here but someMethod3() has arguments passed to it). I should mention that I added a dummy method to ServiceB just to see if it was an issue with someMethod2(). I simply added some logging lines to that method, but the same issue arises for it as well.

My question is, why can't someMethod3 be executed? My guess is that it has to do with the fact that ServiceB is annotated with @MockBean, but not sure exactly.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: I updated the structure of my code above. I apologize for giving the wrong code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a mock for service b, since that's the one being injected into service a. That mock won't call service c's method - that behavior is internal to service b, which isn't of interest in the test for a.